# How to get nearest child node and not the nested ones using DOM or XPATH in PHP

Tags: php, xml, dom, xpath

Having some XML product feed like this:

```
<SHOP>
  <SHOPITEM id="2927" import-code="PREMIER">
    <NAME>productname</NAME>
    <DESCRIPTION>Blah, blah, blah ...</DESCRIPTION>
    <RELATED_PRODUCTS>
      <CODE>PXP-01-01</CODE>
      <CODE>PXP-01-02</CODE>
      <CODE>PXP-01-03</CODE>
    </RELATED_PRODUCTS>
    <FLAGS>
      <FLAG>
        <CODE>news</CODE>
        <ACTIVE>1</ACTIVE>
      </FLAG>
      <FLAG>
        <CODE>action</CODE>
        <ACTIVE>0</ACTIVE>
      </FLAG>
    </FLAGS>
    <CODE>PXS-01-MNCRFT</CODE>
    <EAN>0702811692053</EAN>
    <WEIGHT>0.5</WEIGHT>
    <PRICE>123</PRICE>
    <VAT>21</VAT>
  </SHOPITEM>
</SHOP>
```

and need to get product code in a PHP loop. Seems easy, but using `$item->getElementsByTagName("CODE")` is impossible because I don´t know the order id of the right one CODE node. I have tried using XPATH, but I´m totally lost and do not know how to construct the query to get only the CODE value in SHOP > SHOPITEM > CODE and all the others in `SHOP > SHOPITEM > RELATED_PRODUCTS > CODE` or in `FLAG > CODE` or in `ALTERNATIVE_PRODUCTS > CODE` ... How to exclude these or better ask exactly for the right one?

Comment: Well, XPath syntax uses `/` to separate steps, not `>`, but other than that your `SHOP/SHOPITEM/CODE` path expression selects that one particular `CODE` element and not the other ones.

Comment: Have it like this here, but it seems not to work well. `$query = "//SHOP/SHOPITEM[CODE[1]='$b2bCode']/PRICELISTS/PRICELIST[position()=" . $priceList . "]/STANDARD_PRICE";`

Comment: No idea how to tell why `PRICELISTS` in an XPath doesn't work if the input sample doesn't contain any such `PRICELISTS` elements.  Perhaps edit the question's sample with an input matching the expression and tell us which result you want and how your PHP code looks.

Comment: Have you tried the XPath `SHOP/SHOPITEM/CODE` as suggested?

Answer (score 0):

Using xpath, try it this way

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml_string);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$flags = $xpath->query('//SHOPITEM//FLAGS');
foreach ($flags as $flag)
{   
    foreach ($xpath->query('.//FLAG/CODE',$flag) as $target) {
    echo $target->nodeValue ."\n";}
};
```

Output:

```
news
action
```

Next:

```
$codes = $xpath->query('//SHOPITEM/CODE');

foreach ($codes as $code)
{   
    foreach ($codes as $code) {
    echo $code->nodeValue ."\n";}
};
```

Output:

```
PXS-01-MNCRFT
```

Finally:

```
$rps = $xpath->query('//SHOPITEM/RELATED_PRODUCTS');
foreach ($rps as $rp)
{   
    foreach ($xpath->query('.//CODE',$rp) as $target) {
    echo $target->nodeValue ."\n";}
};
```

Output:

```
PXP-01-01
PXP-01-02
PXP-01-03
```